# how to get the sum of all the elements in here?

Tags: python, list, queue

```
def isempty(qu):
    if qu==[]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def push(qu,item):
    qu.append(item)
    if len(qu)==1:
        front=rear=0
    else:
        rear=len(qu)-1

def pop(qu):
    if isempty(qu):
        return "underflow"
    else:
        item=qu.pop()[0]
        if len(qu)==0:
            front=rear=0
        return item

def peek(qu):
    if isempty(qu):
        return "underflow"
    else:
        front=0
    return qu[front]

def display(qu):
    if isempty(qu):
        print("Queue Empty")
    else:
        front=0
        rear=len(qu)-1
        print(qu[front],"<--- front")
        for a in range(1,rear):
            print(qu[a])
        print(qu[rear],"<--- rear")
def summation():        
    def sum_arr(arr,size):
       if (size == 0):
         return 0
       else:
         return arr[size-1] + sum_arr(arr,size-1)
    n=int(input("Enter number of elements in the queue for addition="))
    queue=[]
    for i in range(0,n):
        queue.append(item)
    print("The list is:")
    print(queue)
    print("sum of items :")
    b=sum_arr(queue,n)
    print(b)

queue=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    print("----Queue Operations----")
    print("1.Push/Enqueue")
    print("2.Pop/Dequeue")
    print("3.Peek")
    print("4.Display Queue")
    print("5.Exit")
    print("6.Summation")
    ch=int(input("Enter your choice="))
    if ch==1:
        item=int(input("Enter element="))
        push(queue,item)
        
    elif ch==2:
        item=pop(queue)
        if item=="underflow":
            print("Queue Empty")
            
        else :
            print("Popped item=",item)
           
    elif ch==3:
        item=peek(queue)
        if item=="underflow":
            print("Queue Empty")
            
        else:
            print("Front most=",item)
           
    elif ch==4:
        display(queue)
        
    elif ch==5:
        break
    elif ch==6:
        summation()
        
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")
```

this is the entire code which we are using here....

this actually for the implementation of queues using lists

it is compulsory to use queues method only here

```
Enter element=4
Enter element=5
Enter element=6
Enter the number of elements in the queue for addition=3
The list is:
[6, 6, 6]
the sum of items :
18
```

here the error is that the elements given are 4,5,6 but only the last element '6' is used for finding the sum thrice...

i hope i answered all the queries asked in the comments.....

any ideas with a little explanation are highly appreciated....

Comment: python has `sum`?

Comment: ya we tried that but still, it does not work in queues...it gives the same error @MZ

Comment: your queue is just a list so I don't see how that doesn't work, but also, what error?

Comment: `queue.append(item)` You're appending the same variable `item` every time through the loop.

Comment: Yes and it isn't even clear where `item` comes from, based on the code actually posted.

Comment: i guess i have answered all the comments in the edited version of the question....hopefully now it would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Zen of Python: Simple is better than complex

No matter what custom function you build, it will never be faster than a builtin.

```
l = [6,6,6]
total = sum(l)
print('The list is: {}'.format(l)
print('the sum of items : {}'.format(total))
```

## If you must still need a custom function

```
def arr_sum(arr):
    holder = 0
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        holder = [holder + i for i in arr if type(i) == int]
        return holder
```

Comment: i know that inbuilt is better...but i am supposed use queues in here ...so any sum with code is helpful....

Comment: I added the custom function to my answer

Comment: yes yes, i was implementing them ......thank you very much after combining both the parts(the simple and the custom one) it worked perfectly thank you very much...@stackz